# Emscripten + Visual Studio + Static Library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, emscripten

I got the basic Emscripten application to work.  One project, containing a main, and what not. However, i am trying to make a little more complex application now. I am looking for either a tutorial, or some help, either way.

What i would like to have is two projects within visual studio. One being the Sample and one being a Static Library.

Within the Static Library would be the Main method (Launcher method), that i would include in any additional samples.

The Sample application would be a Win32 application that imports this static library. Currently this is how my engine is setup, and works well for other platforms as well. I can't get it to work with Emscripten at the moment though.

When i compile the Static library, it produces a *.bc file.  I need to know from there how to include that into my Sample application.

Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

Under Project properties, Emcc Linker, Command Line: add in the "Additional Options" area, the BC Library(s) you want to include as well as additional Emcc commands not covered by Visual Studio.  My entry looks like:

C:\myLibDir\libMyLib.bc -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_main', '_func2']"

Comment: Thanks! Can you give a quick overview of what EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS represent? Is it similar to export in a win32 all?

Comment: Different question, but I'll answer.  Yes it is the API you want to make available to the outside world.  Check out the Emscripten documentation at http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html